# How to use get_user_by in plugin

Tags: plugins, user-meta

I'm trying to find a user's id via a given email address by using 
`get_user_by('email', 'email@address.com')`. I'm using it in a plugin and it's returning false. The same code on the theme level returns the expected user data.

How can I use this function in a plugin?

Comment: Do you use WordPress Multisite? )

Comment: negative. single site install

Comment: Evidently problem is somewhere else. Function execution doesnt depend on where is it. I used it in plugins a number of times.

Comment: Thanks KAGG. Found my issue. It was failing in the unit tests, which has it's own user DB. Testing against the this table worked.

Comment: @psorensen - my best guess would be that you have misspelled the email address in the plugin since it shouldn't matter if the function is used in a plugin or in a theme.